# Correct wrongly formatted dates

Tags: regex, r, date

I have some incorrect dates between good formatted dates, looking something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(col=c("--1.1.11-01","--1.11.12-1","--1.1.13-01","--1.1.14-01","--1.10.10-01","-1.10.11-01","---1.10.12-01","2010-03-31","2010-04-01","2010-04-05"))
```

How can I convert the incorrect format between the existing correctly formatted dates?

I'm able to remove the first dashes, but also the it requires to remove the last 3 characters `-01` or `-1`. So that the corrected values are:

```
desired <- c("1.1.11","1.1.12","1.1.13","1.1.14","1.10.10","1.10.11","1.10.12","2010-03-31","2010-04-01","2010-04-05"))
```

What I'm strangling with is the `-01` part, since by removing these, would also remove part of the correct formatted dates.

EDIT: The format is `mm.dd.yy`

Comment: can you please let us know what is the format of the correct date. I mean dd.mm.yy or mm.dd.yy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple regexp will solve these kinds of problems pretty well:

```
> df <- c("--1.1.11-01","--1.11.12-1","--1.1.13-01","--1.1.14-01","--1.10.10-01","-1.10.11-01","---1.10.12-01","2010-03-31","2010-04-01","2010-04-05")
> df
 [1] "--1.1.11-01"   "--1.11.12-1"   "--1.1.13-01"   "--1.1.14-01"   "--1.10.10-01"  "-1.10.11-01"   "---1.10.12-01"
 [8] "2010-03-31"    "2010-04-01"    "2010-04-05"   
> df <- sub(".*([0-9]{4}\\-[0-9]{2}\\-[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2}\\.[0-9]{1,2}\\.[0-9]{1,2}).*", "\\1", df)
> df
 [1] "1.1.11"     "1.11.12"    "1.1.13"     "1.1.14"     "1.10.10"    "1.10.11"    "1.10.12"    "2010-03-31" "2010-04-01"
[10] "2010-04-05"
```

Note that I made it a character vector instead of data.frame.

The solution itself is just matching one pattern or the other pattern and then dropping the rest by replacing it with the subpattern.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a pretty simple solution using `sub` ...

```
sub('^-+([^-]+).+', '\\1', df$col)
# [1] "1.1.11"     "1.11.12"    "1.1.13"     "1.1.14"     "1.10.10"   
# [6] "1.10.11"    "1.10.12"    "2010-03-31" "2010-04-01" "2010-04-05"
```

Comment: Thanks, I really like your solution, its simple and I understand it :)

Answer (score 3):

Just remove all the non-word characters present at the start or `-01` or `-1` present at the end which was not preceded by `-`+ two digits.

```
> x <- c("--1.1.11-01","--1.11.12-1","--1.1.13-01","--1.1.14-01","--1.10.10-01","-1.10.11-01","---1.10.12-01","2010-03-31","2010-04-01","2010-04-05")
> gsub("^\\W+|(?<!-\\d{2})-0?1$", "", x, perl=T)
 [1] "1.1.11"     "1.11.12"    "1.1.13"     "1.1.14"     "1.10.10"   
 [6] "1.10.11"    "1.10.12"    "2010-03-31" "2010-04-01" "2010-04-05"
```

Comment: Works great. I'm accepting however @LauriK solution on grounds answering question first correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I here observe that if the prefix of a date has an entry as -1 or --1 then only there exists a illegal suffix i.e -01.
You could first take all the values in array.
So you will have an array of "--1.1.11-01","--1.11.12-1","--1.1.13-01","--1.1.14-01","--1.10.10-01","-1.10.11-01"

Now you can check for the prefix if is it -1 or --1. if there exists any such thing then you can mark it as to remove the suffix -01 as well . 
According to the input pattern above I feel that the above strategy would work.

Please let me know if the strategy works